# How to decide n_componets in HashEncoding

Tags: python, categorical-data, natural-language, feature-engineering, categorical-encoding

I want to predict salary for each person depending on the job_roles, Technical skills. Column job_roles have 1500 unique roles.

There is a column Technical skills (which have combination of skills) I have applied TFIDF to transform them into numerical(this has created 16000+ columns).

For 1500 unique roles I want to apply hashing method. How do I decide the optimum  n_components for unique roles.

Comment: It depends on the cost of a collision.  For that reason, it would help us if you could edit your post to include more information about your application.

Comment: @whuber I have edited my post.

Comment: I'm glad you did, because yours is a *completely* different problem than the original post suggested!  The scope of reasonable solutions depends on how much data you have: could you indicate that?

Comment: @whuber I am sorry for my previous improper edits. Please read the post now.